# retofit2 how to post plain String in body

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2

> com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1

My rest API(Post) returns plain string as response

how to post String in body?

My code is

I'm using custom String Converter Factory

```
public final class ToStringConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
        @Override
        public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
            //noinspection EqualsBetweenInconvertibleTypes
            if (String.class.equals(type)) {
                return new Converter<ResponseBody, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    public Object convert(ResponseBody responseBody) throws IOException {
                        return responseBody.string();
                    }
                };
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (String.class.equals(type)) {
                return new Converter<String, RequestBody>() {

                    @Override
                    public RequestBody convert(String value) throws IOException {
                        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
                    }
                };
            }

            return null;
        }


    }
```

and my Retrofit builder is

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(root_url).addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory()).build();
```

and my callback is

```
Callback<String>  callback = new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {



                System.out.println("===>>> onResponse body res "+response.body());
                System.out. println("===>>> onResponse error body res "+response.errorBody());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("===>>> onFailure "+call.toString()+" "+t.toString());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
```

My RetroService interface is

```
public interface RetroService {


    @POST("/validateUser")
    Call<String> login(@Body String body);

}
```

and the API call

```
Call<String> loginCall = service.login(req);
                    loginCall.enqueue(callback);
```

What i'm getting is in onresponse() response.body its always showing as null.

Please clarify what i'm doing wrong.

Thx in adv.

Comment: why do you use converter? and are you sure the server is sending back respose?

Answer (score 0):

I google online, finding that latest GSON can handle plain text response. Add this into gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

Using this in your code

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

// Add log
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                    .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(root_url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
```

Please give a try to see whether you can handle String in response.

This is what I find online, not sure whether it is working for u. Please give a try. [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1151)